# Does Come and Get me allow for more than one opportunity attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The barbarian rage power "Come and Get me" States:

While raging, as a free action the barbarian may leave herself open to attack while preparing devastating counterattacks. Enemies gain a +4 bonus on attack and damage rolls against the barbarian until the beginning of her next turn, but every attack against the barbarian provokes an attack of opportunity from her, which is resolved prior to resolving each enemy attack.

Does this power require you to have the Combat Reflexes ability to use more than one attack of opportunity? Or does this override that need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you require Combat Reflexes feat to use more than one attack of opportunity. [Come and Get Me](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/come-and-get-me-ex) has no language to suggest it is the exception to the rule.

I have checked the [Come and Get Me](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/come-and-get-me-ex) power and compared its language with the language in the description of [AoO](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity) and I have read "provoking an attack of opportunity" and "making an attack of opportunity" are not quite the same.

Come and Get Me makes it so that anyone who attacks you provokes an attack of opportunity in the same way they would provoke an attack of opportunity for moving out of a threatened square.

To make multiple attacks of opportunity you would need the combat reflexes feat.

Another way of looking at it is that characters still "provokes" an attack of opportunity even if the character being "provoked" has no more attacks of opportunity this round or chooses not to take the attack of opportunity.

Comment: So without Combat Reflexes, I can attack one person as many times as they attack me, but can't do another person, unless I take combat reflexes?

Comment: No, you have one attack of opportunity per turn.

Comment: Err, I mean you have one attack of opportunity per round.

Comment: That is most unpleasant...seems like a waste of a rage power now that you are required to dip into Combat Reflexes as well. The damage potential seems considerably less

Comment: Ref: Combat reflexes (http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-reflexes-combat)

Comment: @RuleofThree another way of stating that is "it's a great rage power addition to build on a Combat Reflexes build." The design intent of every little bit isn't "I should be able to take that with any character!"...

Comment: I guess my problem is with the wording of the rage power. While raging, as a free action the barbarian may leave herself open to attack while preparing devastating counterattacks, implies that you are allowed to prepare an attack for each oncoming attack, regardless of Combat Reflexes.

Comment: I do not think it is implying that, but I can see how you would infer it. As I interpret the rules, you simply need combat reflexes to make more than one attack of opportunity.

Comment: Looked at another way, it's an extra attack per round without needing to engage in clever tactics (and therefore possibly blowing your chance at a Full Attack) and a way to punish attacks -- or *more* than one extra attack per round if you wind up taking CR as well.  Not bad value for a feat.